# For a closed $G_\delta$ set $F\subseteq X,$ does there exist a continuous function $f:X\to [0,1]$ such that $f=0$ on $F$ and $f\neq 0$ outside $F?$

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

(All spaces are Hausdorff.)

This question is a [variant of my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3062652/for-every-closed-set-f-in-a-completely-regular-space-x-does-there-exist-a-n).

Let $X$ be a completely regular space, that is, for every closed set $F\subseteq X$ and $x\not\in F,$ there exists a continuous function $g:X\to [0,1]$ such that $g(F) = \{0\}$ and $g(x) =1.$

> **Question**: For every closed  $G_\delta$ set $F\subseteq X,$ does there exist a continuous function $f:X\to [0,1]$ such that $f=0$ on $F$ and $f\neq 0$ outside $F?$

A subset $U\subseteq X$ is a **zero set** if there exists a continuous function $g:X\to [0,1]$ such that $g^{-1}(\{0\}) = U.$

It is well-known that if $X$ is normal then all closed $G_\delta$ sets are zero sets.

However, I am not sure whether the same holds for completely regular space.

Comment: I know that $X$ normal implies that all closed $G_\delta$'s are zero-sets, but I believe the reverse does not hold. If it did your question would be useless. Do you have a reference ? "well-known" it is not, it's not mentioned in Engelking, a standard reference for such matters.

Comment: Note that this can only be true when $F$ is closed *and* $G_\delta$. You cannot ask this for all closed sets.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma yes, you are right. I have edited my post.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma by the way, if the converse holds, why would by question be useless?

Comment: Because then (if your reformulated question were true) every closed $G_\delta$ set would be a zero-set and thus $X$ would be normal. And there are lots of non-normal completely regular spaces which would be immediate counterexamples.

Comment: I doubt it. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/243861/is-each-lindelof-closed-bar-g-delta-set-of-a-tychonoff-space-functionally-cl.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma The claim concerning $X$  normal is covered by Engelking 1.5.11.

Comment: @PaulFrost that is the direction I agreed with, yes. The OP originally claimed that if all closed $G_\delta$ sets are zero-sets then $X$ is normal. This I doubt the truth of, as said.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I see, and I also doubt it is true. I guess there is a class of spaces containing the normal spaces characterized by the property that the closed $G_\delta$-sets agree with the zero-sets. But I doubt that it is the class of completely regular spaces.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I think the correct characterisation is as follows: Let $X$ be a normal Hausdorff topological space and $F\subseteq X$ is a closed subset. Then $F$ is a zero set if and only if $F$ if $F$ is $G_\delta.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a well-known counterexample. Let $S$ be the Sorgenfrey line, that is the real
line endowed with the Sorgenfrey topology (generated by the base consisting of half-intervals $[a,b)$, $a<b$). It is well-known that a product $X=S\times S$ is a Tychonoff but non-normal space (see, for instance, Examples 1.4.4 and 2.3.12 in [Eng]). Let $D=\{(x,-x)\in S\times S: x\in S\}$. Then any subset $Y$ of $D$ is closed in $X$, and we have $2^{|D|}=2^{\frak c}$ such subsets. Moreover, since $Y=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N} Y+[0,1/n)\times [0,1/n)$, $Y$ is a $G_\delta$-subset of $X$. 
On the other hand, let $C$ be a countable dense subset of $X$. By Theorem 2.1.9 in [Eng], each continuous real-valued function $f$ on $X$ is uniquely determined by its restriction on $C$, so there are at most $\frak c^\omega=\frak c$ such functions. Thus most subsets of $D$ are not zero-sets.

*References*

[Eng] Ryszard Engelking, *General Topology*, 2nd ed., Heldermann, Berlin, 1989.